# Something is wrong with my code on .change(function(){});

Tags: javascript

Hello can I ask some help on this, I'm trying to alert the value of the selected item for select, but it does not alert(), I've search for answers and it seems that my code is the same with the answers given,  here is the sample of my code

**Code.js**

```js
<script>
        $("#sort").change(function(){
            alert('Selected value: ' + $(this).val());
        });

</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<select id="sort">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I can't seem to see the error on my code.

Comment: document ready handler...

Comment: Unable to reproduce it :(

Comment: I hope that `<script` part in HTML is a typo

Comment: Presumable a duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Comment: Working here .... https://jsfiddle.net/3crjd0ba/

Comment: @Sandeep Nayak oh yes, wait let me edit it

Comment: hey how did that happen it worked on https://jsfiddle.net/3crjd0ba/ , but when in my file it does not

Comment: You are most likely trying to bind the event handler before the element exist. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Wrap your script with `document.ready` ..updated here https://jsfiddle.net/3crjd0ba/1/